# Why cant my WIFI and LAN clients not see each other on the network but both have internet?

Tags: subnet

Oky so i have a small network consisting of 1 Tenda WAN router that does the PPPoe "dialing" and a Tenda AP for WIFI because the Tenda Router's WIFI is not as good as the AP. I plug a LAN cable from the router to a gigabit un-managed switch and from the switch a LAN cable goes to the WAN port on the AP. The LAN ip is 192.168.2.x and the WIFI ip is 192.168.0.x I have a internet connection on both the LAN and WIFI but the LAN clients cant see the WIFI clients and vice versa.

If anyone can give me guidance i would really appreciate it.

Comment: "See" is a bit vague. Do you mean direct connections by IP address, or do you mean listing the other network's devices in the Windows "Network" page, or what?

Comment: “a LAN cable goes to the WAN port on the AP” – that’s not ideal. I suggest you change the setup so the AP doesn’t act as a router.

Comment: @grawity. If you ping a client on the WIFI network from LAN network it fails and vice versa

Comment: @DanielB   the options i have on the AP is PPPoe, Dynamic and static. which one should i sure?

Answer (score 0):

> and from the switch a LAN cable goes to the WAN port on the AP. The LAN ip is 192.168.2.x and the WIFI ip is 192.168.0.x

If it has a "WAN" port, it is not just an AP – **it is also a router.** If it provides you with different IP addresses than your main LAN uses – it has to be a router.

So all of the previously posted threads about "chaining two routers" or "using second router to expand Wi-Fi" apply to your as well. Your two options are:

1. Switch the AP to "bridge" mode, so that it would just expand the 'WAN' subnet instead of creating a new network. This is the recommended option, especially if you want both devices to provide Wi-Fi with the same SSID – clients will be able to seamlessly switch between the two.
2. Configure routing so that the main router knows where to send packets for the "AP"s addresses. (That is, at least for a start, a static route with destination=192.168.0.0/24 and gateway=192.168.2.x. I'm not sure if it'll be enough.)

---

> the options i have on the AP is PPPoe, Dynamic and static. which one should i

None of them – they all just change how the AP obtains its "WAN" IP address, but they do not change its global behavior (i.e. it'll still remain a router and will still have a separate network of its own).

What you're looking for is an option that says **"bridge mode"** (or sometimes "AP mode"). *Some* home routers have it as a dedicated option in a separate page.

If the AP device doesn't have such an option, but has some wired LAN ports: just use one of those, as they're almost always bridged to Wi-Fi already. (You'll often see this referred to as "LAN-to-LAN" connection.)

In any case, you will also need to **disable the AP's "DHCP server" feature**, as it's redundant with your main router, and more importantly would be providing misleading information to clients. (Bridge mode *might* disable DHCP service automatically, or it might not – always check.)

Comment: Holy Crap dude it works, you're a genius!!!!!!
Thank you very much for the answer!